# SQL Server Developer Edition 2012 or 2014 - Download

Tags: sql-server

I've heard (I am pretty sure) that Developer Edition is free of charge and for downloading it registration is not required. But when I started looking for it today I could not find where to get it from. Is my understanding wrong or right? Sorry I didn't find a similar question here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Developer Edition is free

As of **March 31, 2016** [Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition is now free](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/) for SQL Server 2014 and up for Visual Studio Dev essential members (which is free as well).

For all editions, see [How to buy SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server/purchasing.aspx).

If you want to *explore* SQL Server, you can download SQL Server Evaluation Edition for 180 days, and then purchase it.

- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2014 & 2016 Evaluation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2014-sp3/)
- [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Evaluation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29066) (no longer available)

Answer (score 9):

It is now free as of 31 March 2016:

[Microsoft SQL Server Developer Edition is now free](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/) (SQL Server Team Blog)

You can upgrade your current SQL Express edition to Developer:

1. Download the appropriate edition (x86 or x64)
2. Mount the .iso and run the installer package
3. Select "Maintenance"
4. Select "Edition Upgrade"
5. Follow the prompts and select the Express instance that you wish to upgrade.

To enable SQL Agent:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_configure 'agent xps', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_configure
```