# Where can I find the SQL Server to download?

Tags: sql-server

I am new here, and I would like to ask: where can i download the latest SQL Server so I can start practising on my PC?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/03/31/microsoft-sql-server-developer-edition-is-now-free/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Developer Edition 2012 or 2014 - Download](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102208/sql-server-developer-edition-2012-or-2014-download)

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN), they have good documentation and links for downloading all the versions, including future version previews. Additionally, there are links for tutorials, text references, as well as various other resources you'll find useful throughout your learning process.

Here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590198(v=sql.1).aspx